# Drag and Move an object even not touching the object but not teleporting the object

Tags: java, android

How to Drag and Move an object even not touching the object but not teleporting the object, now when i touch another place on the screen the player just teleport where i touch.

```
playerPoint.set(x,y)` >> is to set the player location x and y

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            playerPoint.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
    }

    return true;
    //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: When i touch point 1 the object render at point 1, when i touch point 2 the object render at point 2 instantly.

Comment: Do you mean teleporting?

Comment: yes i mean teleporting, sry my bad